# Got on trouble Vlan VM need help. (VLAN, KVM-VM)

Tags: networking, 22.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vlan

I want to create a vlan on ubuntu server and want to create a ubuntu server vm mit kvm but I have not enough lan ports so I want to create a van to create the vm that uses the vlan to get an private ip address!

but at this point I get on trouble to find a step by step guide to get it to work

I am still noob I have already 10hours on that spent but found no solution even chat got and bard cant help me because they provide just wrong information! :(

I hope outside there is someone that is able to help me and has the needed knowledge to provide me what I have to do !

I have tried that but after setup I was unable to connect over the vlan ip address I have connected the vm to a bridge and the bridge was connected to the vlan but when I used ssh to access the vm over the vlans Ip address I came out at the main server where I had created the vm!:  https://ubuntu.com/blog/kvm-hyphervisor